# shortening for loops and some instructions

Tags: python, performance

```
X1 = 5
Y1 = 9
X0 = 2
Y0 = 7
List = []

unity = -1 if Y0 > Y1 else 1
unitx = -1 if X0 > X1 else 1
for y in range(Y0, Y1+unity, unity):
    for x in range(X0, X1+unitx, unitx):
        List.append((str(x), str(y)))
    temp = X0
    X0 = X1
    X1 = temp
    unitx *= -1
print(List)
```

Basically, the code steps through a rectangle area defined by (X0, Y0), and (X1,Y1). Is there another coding strategy for the nested for loop, and swapping X0 and X1? For example, recursive methods, which I do not think so. I hope the code can be as efficient and as readable as possible. The photo below shows one of the possible cases of this script.
[image]

Comment: Is the indentatiion correct in the snippet? The second half of your for loop doesn't even use `y`.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but y and x are used in the List.append() line

Comment: I'd say this should go on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than stack exchange since your code works but I'll help if I can

Comment: I reckon the way you've done it is fairly efficient and easy to read, maybe just change for example `unitx` to `step_x` so it's clearer what it's for. Other methods I believe would need if statements so your way is probably one of the best ways to do it

Comment: step_x is indeed much better, and, just found out that ```x, y = y, x``` can swap variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to walk on all cells (don't clear if the path must be that) this do the trick:
First rows, normalize X1>X0, generator is delegated to iterools.product that do the job.
Lastly map, cast types to string

```
import itertools
if X0>X1:
    X1, X0 = X0, X1
if Y0 > Y1:
    Y1, Y0 = Y0, Y1
print([map(str,x) for x in itertools.product(range(X0, X1+1), range(Y0, Y1+1))])
```

The outcome:

```
[['2', '7'], ['2', '8'], ['2', '9'], ['3', '7'], ['3', '8'], ['3', '9'], ['4', '7'], ['4', '8'], ['4', '9'], ['5', '7'], ['5', '8'], ['5', '9']]
```

Comment: I don't think this is right, as it wont work when X0 is greater than X1, or Y0 is greater than Y1. And, x should be reversing again and again, not 789, 789, 789, but 789, 987, 789. though y is indeed incrementing/ decrementing without reversing again and again. And, X shall change multiple times before Y changes once.